# Specify OCTETSTRING as hex with custom ASN1 object in OpenSSL Config File

Tags: openssl

I am trying to encode an ASN.1 SEQUENCE that should come out like this:

```
0042:    |  30 59               ; SEQUENCE (59 Bytes)
0044:    |  |  30 13                ; SEQUENCE (13 Bytes)
0046:    |  |  |  06 07             ; OBJECT_ID (7 Bytes)
0048:    |  |  |  |  2a 86 48 ce 3d 02 01
         |  |  |  |     ; 1.2.840.10045.2.1 ECC
004f:    |  |  |  06 08             ; OBJECT_ID (8 Bytes)
0051:    |  |  |     2a 86 48 ce 3d 03 01 07
         |  |  |        ; 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 ECDSA_P256 (x962P256v1)
0059:    |  |  03 42                ; BIT_STRING (42 Bytes)
005b:    |  |     00
005c:    |  |     04 f4 df ac 6c 8d e5 b0  6c 55 29 13 1e fe 35 9a
006c:    |  |     c6 06 57 97 ca c5 6f 1b  9e 3b cd 46 f3 01 91 0e
007c:    |  |     2a 5b 93 fe 6b d3 04 06  44 6c 54 e7 f5 b5 f5 81
008c:    |  |     d4 a4 eb 12 9f e7 ae 27  f6 97 c8 f6 d3 e6 c8 9b
009c:    |  |     3a
```

Of course, this is an ECDSA P256 ECC key.  When I try to create a similar structure in an arbitrary extension, like - say - SubjectDirectoryAttributes, I cannot figure out the right OpenSSL config file syntax to properly encode the BIT_STRING.

Consider this openssl config file [ossl.req.config.stackoverflow.txt]:

```
[ req ]
distinguished_name     = req_dn
req_extensions         = req_ext
prompt                 = no
encrypt_key            = no
digest                 = sha256
version=2

[ req_dn ]
C=US
ST=SomeState
CN=Something

[ req_ext ]
# SubjectDirectoryAttributes
2.5.29.9=ASN1:SEQUENCE:EccPublicKeyInfo

[EccPublicKeyInfo]
X=SEQUENCE:ECDSA_PublicKeyInfo

[ecdsa256_alg]
algorithm=OID:1.2.840.10045.2.1
parameter=OID:1.2.840.10045.3.1.7

[ ECDSA_PublicKeyInfo ]
SubjectPublicKeyInfo=SEQUENCE:ecdsa256_alg
hex1=BITWRAP,BITSTR:0x04112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
hex2=INTEGER:0x04112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
hex3=BITWRAP,INTEGER:0x04112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
```

These attempts at formatting the hex value produces the following effects:

```
snip...
00bd:    |                       30 64      ; SEQUENCE (64 Bytes)
00bf:    |                          30 13   ; SEQUENCE (13 Bytes)
00c1:    |                          |  06 07    ; OBJECT_ID (7 Bytes)
00c3:    |                          |  |  2a 86 48 ce 3d 02 01
         |                          |  |     ; 1.2.840.10045.2.1 ECC
00ca:    |                          |  06 08    ; OBJECT_ID (8 Bytes)
00cc:    |                          |     2a 86 48 ce 3d 03 01 07
         |                          |        ; 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 ECDSA_P256 (x962P256v1)
00d4:    |                          03 26   ; BIT_STRING (26 Bytes)
00d6:    |                          |  00
00d7:    |                          |  03 23 00 30 78 30 34 31  31 32 32 33 33 34 34 35
00e7:    |                          |  35 36 36 37 37 38 38 39  39 61 61 62 62 63 63 64
00f7:    |                          |  64 65 65 66 66
00fc:    |                          02 10   ; INTEGER (10 Bytes)
00fe:    |                          |  04 11 22 33 44 55 66 77  88 99 aa bb cc dd ee ff
010e:    |                          03 13   ; BIT_STRING (13 Bytes)
0110:    |                             00
0111:    |                             02 10 04 11 22 33 44 55  66 77 88 99 aa bb cc dd
0121:    |                             ee ff
```

Notice that the first BIT_STRING is the input hex string interpreted as ASCII, not HEX (line 00d7).

Notice also, that both the INTEGER and the BITWRAP INTEGER correctly interpret the hex input string from the config file.  However, neither one produces the desired output because the INTEGER type is encoded into either the type directly (line 00fc) or inside the BIT_STRING (line 0111).  Neither of these are correct, since the goal is to match the output on line 0059/005b above where a BIT_STRING wraps a bare hex value.

Both the documentation: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ASN1_generate_nconf.html
and a cursory inspection of the OpenSSL source code: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/asn1/asn1_gen.c
seem to agree that it should be possible to pass a hex string to BITSTR and OCTETSTRING, but I've tried more combinations than these and either I get the ASCII interpretation of line 00d7, or an error parsing the config file.

Does anyone know how to format the config file, or can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The commands I am using to attempt this are:

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -out ecc256.pem
openssl req -new -key ecc256.pem -out ecc256_req.pem -config ossl.req.config.stackoverflow.txt
```

Using Openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the right way to format the extension string is:

```
hex1=FORMAT:HEX,BITSTR:04112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
```

Things to notice: `FORMAT:HEX` *must* come before the type.  The OpenSSL parser is treating the input string as an array of comma separate strings, so `BITSTR:0411...` is the `TYPE:VALUE` part of the string.  All other modifiers, including `FORMAT:HEX` must come first.
Also, unlike the `INTEGER` type that detects and honors the `0x` prefix, `FORMAT:HEX` must NOT have this prefix.

Changing the configuration file to:

```
[ ECDSA_PublicKeyInfo ]
SubjectPublicKeyInfo=SEQUENCE:ecdsa256_alg
hex1=FORMAT:HEX,BITSTR:04112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00
```

produces the expected sequence exactly 0x59 byte long.

```
00bb:    |                       30 59      ; SEQUENCE (59 Bytes)
00bd:    |                          30 13   ; SEQUENCE (13 Bytes)
00bf:    |                          |  06 07    ; OBJECT_ID (7 Bytes)
00c1:    |                          |  |  2a 86 48 ce 3d 02 01
         |                          |  |     ; 1.2.840.10045.2.1 ECC
00c8:    |                          |  06 08    ; OBJECT_ID (8 Bytes)
00ca:    |                          |     2a 86 48 ce 3d 03 01 07
         |                          |        ; 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 ECDSA_P256 (x962P256v1)
00d2:    |                          03 42   ; BIT_STRING (42 Bytes)
00d4:    |                             00
00d5:    |                             04 11 22 33 44 55 66 77  88 99 aa bb cc dd ee ff
00e5:    |                             00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77  88 99 aa bb cc dd ee ff
00f5:    |                             00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77  88 99 aa bb cc dd ee ff
0105:    |                             00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77  88 99 aa bb cc dd ee ff
0115:    |                             00
```